# Rails 3- Active_admin - Show field in the new page but not in the edit

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, formtastic, activeadmin

I have a model called user. I want to show the password field just on the create page, not the edit one.

```
ActiveAdmin.register User do
    form do |f|
       f.inputs "User Details" do
          f.input :first_name
          f.input :last_name
          f.input :email
          if f.object.new_record?
              f.input :password
          end

       end
    f.buttons
    end
 end
```

This is what I tried but using .new_record? function all my fields disappear from the edit page.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was to use a partial.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone, like me, that comes along later: The answer provided by Meskallito works, but you may need to  play with fieldsets to accommodate for ActiveAdmin/Formtastic oddities that show up sometimes when you insert logic, depending on how your form is structured. For example, when I implemented his answer, I did this:

```
form do |f|
  f.inputs 'Account' do
    f.inputs "Credentials" do
      f.input :email,                   :label => "Email Address"
    end
    if f.object.id.nil?
      f.inputs "Password" do
        f.input :password,              :label => "Password"
        f.input :password_confirmation, :label => "Password Confirmation"
      end
    end
    ...
  end
end
```

Now the fieldset with the password and password_confirmation fields displays only when I'm creating a new user, and not when I'm editing a user. The new_record? function Tony used originally might have worked as well, since he said that when he tried it his fields disappeared, which may have been due to this issue.

BTW, I would have just commented on the original answer by Meskallito, but I didn't have enough rep. :-)

Comment: Check this:https://github.com/gregbell/active_admin/issues/887

This is a bug in active_admin.

Answer (score 0):

I've used that:

```
if f.object.id.nil?
    f.input :password
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
  if f.object.new_record?
    f.input :password
    f.input :password_confirmation
  end
```